# Alternative for storing Image in Database Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a simple e-commerce app using django, I need to store images but i realized that using database is a bad idea. I need detailed help on what i could do.

Comment: Use a `FileField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField